# Positively constrained parameters in LAD LASSO

Tags: lasso

I am looking for an implementation of LAD LASSO method with constraints on coefficients, such as non-negative beta coefficients for example.

$\min_{\beta} \left| \mathbb{y} - \mathbb{X} \boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1 + \lambda \left|\boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1 $

Are there any packages available with such properties? Also interested are there any methods which combines elastic net types of penatly with LAD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could always try treating this as a Linear program.

$$\min_{\beta} ||y-X\beta|| \\
\beta_i\ge0 $$

Comment: I am doing it now, feeding the optimization problem to a linear solver. However I thought, may be there are more computationally efficient solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `flare` package?

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flare/index.html

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flare/vignettes/vignette.pdf

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flare/flare.pdf

I believe your function call will look something like this:

```
model = flare.slim(X=design.matrix, Y=response
                  , method='lq' # Lasso shrinkage
                  , q=1         # LAD loss
                  )
```

Comment: Thank you for the links. I couldn't figure out how to specify constraints in this package. Is it possible in principle?

Comment: Just found out that it's not possible to specify constraints on parameters in flare package